# C# Unmanaged Exports of array to python

Tags: c#, python, unmanaged

I am using Robert Giesecke's DLLExport library to allow me to export a c# dll that can be accessed by a python application.   I have figured out how to call for basic types, such as integers, double and strings, but I also need to return arrays of strings or integers back from the c# dll to python.

I tried defining it like:

```
[DllExport("Test7", System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static int[]  Test7()
{
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int[] info = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            info[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(rnd.Next()), 0));

        }
        return info; 
    }
```

I also tried to use the example from the "Unmanaged Exports with Arrays" topic, with my c# code being:

```
[DllExport("Test8", System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static void Test8(int length, out IntPtr info)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int[] valList = new int[length];
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                valList[length] = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(rnd.Next()), 0));

            }
            info = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(valList.Length * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(int)));
            Marshal.Copy(valList, 0, info, length);
        }
```

The basic test function is to create an integer array of a length provided by the function, and to return the value back to the caller.

On the python side, I have a simple code to test:

```
import os
import ctypes
import numpy as np
output = ctypes.CDLL(".\\pythontstl.dll").Test7(10)
```

and I tried

```
  array_holder = ctypes.ARRAY()
  output = ctypes.CDLL(".\\pythontst1.dll").Test8(10,array_holder)
```

In both cases, I get an OSError: [WinError -532462766] Windows Error 0xe0434352.   I am learning python so it may be a syntax or call that I might be missing, but the output = ctypes.CDLL(".\pythontst1.dll").Test6('hello') code works and returns a string (along with the other test functions I have for the primitives).

Comment: There is an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48481504/403671